# Not able to send email via php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send mail via php script and comparatively new to php. I wrote below code:

```
<?php
   $to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "This is simple text message.";
   $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
?>
```

But I not able to send email and retval is returning false. I am also not able to debug the actual error. Please suggest how can I find the root cause?

Comment: Do you have a mail server running on your machine?

Comment: Yes. I have setup a SMTP server

Comment: Look for any possible error messages in its logs

Comment: Check if sendmail is running, if it is check the logs. `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: My weapon of choice for building and sending emails is http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: switch to swiftmailer or use mandrillapp to send emails